# Java can't find main class in JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet, mainclass

I wrote a JApplet program in Java.

Now when I Run the program it tells me that the class wasn't found in project.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
package assignment1q6.pkg1;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Assignment1Q61 extends JApplet 
{
    public void paint(Graphics canvas) 
    {
        canvas.drawArc(150, 160, 100, 100, 270, 180);
        canvas.drawOval(250, 175, 70, 70);
        canvas.drawArc(235, 75, 100, 100, 180, 180);
        canvas.drawArc(320, 160, 100, 100, 90, 180);
        canvas.drawArc(235, 245, 100, 100, 0, 180);
        canvas.fillOval(265, 190, 40, 40);
    }
}
```

I added more code. Still when I run it, it says the same thing.

Comment: How and where are you running it?

Comment: Applets don't run in the same sense as other Java programs do, they are suppose to be loaded by a browser (or the applet viewer), so you generally can't "run" them.  Also, you've violated the paint chain, you should be calling `super.paint(canvas)` before doing any custom painting

Comment: [This is how Applets runs](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/JavaInDOS.html) !!!

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I'm running it on NetBeans IDE

Comment: Tip: Add @Kiki (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify the person of a new comment.

Comment: *"I added more code. Still when I run it, it says the same thing."*  Programming 'by magic' never works..

Answer (score 2):

To run applet in netbeans you just rigth click on applet file and select `Run File`. The applet will start in Applet viewer.
[image]